# A question about connected regular bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G = (V = V_1 \cup V_2,E)$ be a connected regular bipartite graph of degree $n+1$ with vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ of size $|S|$.

If we choose $|S|$ vertices from $V$ with at least one vertex each from $V_1$ and $V_2$ (call this set $S$), can we show that there are two vertices in $S$ that are neighbors?

What I've done so far:

I tried to get a contradiction by considering the possibility $S$ has no vertices that are neighbors, but I could not make much progress. In my working, I tried to get a contradiction with respect to the connectedness of the group. The crux of my idea was to show that bipartition of vertices is not unique and it looked so natural, however there seems to be a small flaw in my argument. It's not fully complete.

It'd be really helpful if I get an hint.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to show it by induction on $n$?

Comment: hello, not yet, I was wondering if there's a way to work with this argument. Its one less than what we we actually want.

Comment: We can of course guess what $S$ is, but it is better if you specify the definition of $S$ in the text.

Comment: sure, I have edited the question.

Comment: And another question: $|S|=\binom{2n+1}{n}$ or $|S|=\binom{2n+1}{n}+1$? In the first case there is a counterexample already for $n=2$.

Comment: I was wondering if |S| can be $\binom{2n+1}{n}$. For the other case, I think I have found a solution. If there's a counter example, then I'll close the question.

Comment: I agree with @pancake's reasoning below. And my "counterexample" contained an error, although the graph was connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not certain if I misunderstood the question but I fail to find counterexample for $n=2$ mentioned by kabenyuk.
This is my attempt at a proof by contradiction:

Let's assume there exists such a set $S$ without any edges and $|V_1| = |V_2| = |S|$.

Let's consider:

- $C_1$ as vertices in both $V_1$ and $S$,
- $C_2$ as vertices in both $V_2$ and $S$,
- $L_1$ as vertices in $V_1$ and not in $S$, and
- $L_2$ as vertices in $V_2$ and not in $S$.

We can see that: $$0 <|C_1|=|S|-|C_2|=|V_2|-|C_2|=|L_2|$$ and similarly $0 <|C_2|=|L_1|$.

Because we assume that there are no edges between vertices of $C_1$ and $C_2$, all edges from $C_1$ must go to $L_2$: by assumption about $S$ and because the graph is bipartite.

That means all edges from $L_2$ must go to $C_1$, because the graph is regular and $|C_1|=|L_2|$.

That means the graph is not connected as there are no edges between $C_1 \cup L_2$ and $L_1 \cup C_2$, $|L_2|=|C_1|>0$, and $|L_1|=|C_2|>0$. This is a contradiction as the graph is connected.
That means that either no such graph exists or each set $S$ must have at least one edge.

Comment: I do not think you have misunderstood the question; I think this is a perfectly good solution! (And it implies a more general statement: in any connected $k$-regular bipartite graph with $N$ vertices on each side, the two sides are the only two independent sets of order $N$. It does not matter how $k$ and $N$ are related.) I suspect that the counterexample mentioned by @kabenyuk is for the case where the graph is not necessarily connected.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. But assuming the graph is not connected would make it trivial to find example for almost any size of S. And yeah the uniqueness of this coloring is quite interesting implication.

Comment: Hello, I was playing with this idea for some time and my plan was to get a contradiction by showing that there exists another bipartition of the vertex sets which would contradict the connectedness. My question and the part where I got stuck was here: how do we show that all edges from L2 go to C1? Could you explain this part? Couldn't some edges go to C2 from L2?

Comment: I was thinking about C1 but somehow ended up with S.

Comment: To answer the question:
Count the number of edges that vertices of C1 and L2 are a part of.
Because the graph is regular you get (n+1)*|C1| where n+1 is degree of a vertex.
And similarily (n+1)*|L2|.
|L2|=|C1| so if all edges from C1 go to L2 there is no edge left to keep the connectivity.

Comment: oh okay got it. It really feels great because I was looking for this and I missed it. This was my first idea and I thought it was all okay until I found a flaw in my argument. Now that's solved. Thank you so much!!